# Move through DataGridView and load Pictures without freezing UI

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where users are moving through keyup and keydown.

For now I am using the keyup Event to refresh the image in the imageBox depending on the value from one column. It works fine if the user only moves one row down or up. The problem is that if a user whats to move quickly few rows by tapping a few times up or down key the UI always freezes for some time.

How can I prevent the freezing of the UI and make the picture loading "backgroundwork"?

So far my Code:

```
private void LoadPicture(string path)
{
    threadworker = new Thread(() => pictureBox1.Image = path);
    threadworker.Start();
}

public void datenübergeben()
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Bild1"].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
    {
        LoadPicture(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Bild1"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't access GUI controls in a separate thread.  Never use an empty Try-Catch.

Comment: Okay now without try-catch any solutions?

Comment: Consider using async task it will not block the UI, but images will be displayed with a delay. Inform me on how it goes, or if you need a code snippet on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that can be usefull:

Create a sub-routine to act between the Grid move and the LoadPicture. INstead you call LoadPicture, call that routine.

This routine will:

1- Get the current GRID row or picture name;

2- Start a Task.Delay for few milliseconds or even 1 second;

3- Get again the current GRID row or picture into another variable and compare with the first one (step 1);

If there is no change, call LoadPicture...